# How to use ASP .Net core with angular 6?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm starting with angular(little bit more experienced with Asp.Net core).
I wanted to use .Net core, because I like the direction MS is taking(and I'm quite fluent in .Net :) ).

What I did:

1. Upgrade VS 2017 and VS Code to latest version
2. Updated npm ( `npm update npm -g` )
3. `dotnet new angular`
4. Updated everything( with https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-update-all). Also did a `npm audit fix`
5. Ran the app(`dotnet run` )
6. Go to http://localhost:5000

This gave a lot of errors in console:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\angular-test>dotnet run Hosting environment: Production Content root path: C:\Users\xxxx\angular-test Now listening on: http://localhost:5000 Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
      An unhandled exception has occurred: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\xxxx\angular-test\ClientApp\dist\main-server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at findBootModule (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\uwz4m2yz.rjc:111:17)
    at findRenderToStringFunc (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\uwz4m2yz.rjc:116:28)
    at renderToStringImpl (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\uwz4m2yz.rjc:75:51)
    at C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\eikzpvcj.v2i:114:19
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\eikzpvcj.v2i:133:38)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:182:13) Current directory is: C:\Users\xxxx\angular-test

Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\xxxx\angular-test\ClientApp\dist\main-server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at findBootModule (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\uwz4m2yz.rjc:111:17)
    at findRenderToStringFunc (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\uwz4m2yz.rjc:116:28)
    at renderToStringImpl (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\uwz4m2yz.rjc:75:51)
    at C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\eikzpvcj.v2i:114:19
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\eikzpvcj.v2i:133:38)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:182:13)
```

And this on the webpage:

> Error. An error occurred while processing your request. Request ID:
>   0HLF1EQKVCJ2V:00000001
>
> Development Mode Swapping to Development environment will display more
>   detailed information about the error that occurred.
>
> Development environment should not be enabled in deployed
>   applications, as it can result in sensitive information from
>   exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging,
>   development environment can be enabled by setting the
>   ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and
>   restarting the application.

What did I miss?
Or what would you advise me to start a project with Asp.Net core and angular 6(I like the idea of HMR, and I want that everything is hosted by asp.net core(static resources and the service).

**Edit**
I tried to use development environement(with `SET ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`), but then it crash directly when running the app(I don't have to go on the webpage):

```
C:\Users\xxxx\angular-test>dotnet run
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Application startup exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Cannot find module './wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json'
Error: Cannot find module './wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\xxxx\angular-test\webpack.config.js:37:27)
    at createWebpackDevServer (C:\Users\xxxx\angular-test\node_modules\aspnet-webpack\WebpackDevMiddleware.js:214:31)
    at createWebpackDevServer (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\xwjt2knh.npy:74:50)
    at C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\kn0wvgm3.vrx:114:19
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\kn0wvgm3.vrx:133:38)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:182:13)) ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException: Cannot find module './wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json'
```

Comment: You don’t mention at all how you actually created the web application and configured your SPA to run inside of it.. – I personally would recommend you to start with the Angular SPA template that comes with ASP.NET Core. That already comes with a working integration and you can launch it out of the box. It was also recently updated to Angular 6 iirc.

Comment: @poke Yes I do, with `dotnet new angular` it creates a starting point of an Asp.Net Core app with an angular app in it. But its definitely in Angular 4.

Comment: Oh, I missed your step 3, somehow read an `ng init` there.

Comment: Even though it comes with Angular templates, the best approach is just create two separate applications one with Asp.Net Core + Web API and another with Angular.  And you can enable CORS on your Asp.Net and run them on separate ports,  or just publish your angular dist folder to Asp.Net root folder.

Comment: @skagini : I don't want two separate port, so it left me with having to publish in the dist folder. Any idea how I could do this, with the HMR support then?